# How to make a html table that its width dynamically adjusts

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I want to know how to create a table that dynamically adjusts its width based on number of columns(depends on how many the user wants) with a fixed width of 150px each.

My client wants the table to also scroll horizontally if it exceeds it's container's width. ( I think using **overflow-x: scroll**)

a simple example would be fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by adding the table in a container, with max-width and overflow defined:

```css
.table-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
    <td>c3</td>
    <td>c4</td>
    <td>c5</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</div>
```